# Jolt giving values as root

Tags: jolt

Here's my input data :

```
[
```

{
"TEST1": "abcd",
"TEST2": "xyz",
"TEST3": "08"
},
{
"TEST1": "abcd",
"TEST2": "xyz",
"TEST3": "20"
}
]

Output

```
[
```

{
"TEST1": "root",
"TEST2": "xyz",
"TEST3": ["08","20"]
}

]

Expected Output

```
[
```

{
"TEST1": "abcd",
"TEST2": "xyz",
"TEST3": ["08","20"]
}

]

Jolt specs

[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"*": {
"TEST3": "@(1,TEST2).TEST3"
}
}
},
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"*": {
"$1": "[#2].TEST1",
"$": "[#2].TEST2",
"@.TEST3": "[#2].TEST3"
}
}
}

]

Can you please help me in achieving the excpected output

Answer (score 1):

Check this spec

```
[
  //Concat the TEST1 and TEST2 to temp
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "temp": "=concat(@(1,TEST1),':',@(1,TEST2))"
      }
    }
 },
  //Group the values by shifting TEST3
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "TEST3": "@(1,temp)"
      }
    }
 },
  // Assign the keys to the node named key and value to the node nameed value
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[#2].key",
        "$": "[#2].value"
      }
    }
  },
  //Shift and assign the respective values to the TEST1, TEST2 and TEST3
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": {
          "*:*": {
            "$(0,1)": "[&3].TEST1",
            "$(0,2)": "[&3].TEST2"
          }
        },
        "key": "[&1].TEST3"
      }
    }
  }


]
```